# can`t read from key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'

Tags: cassandra, thrift

I´m trying to read from cassandra 1.1.6. This is the script in cassandra-cli

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY aaa
with column_type = 'Standard'
and comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)';
```

When I tried to read with thrift with

```
c1.getColumn().getValue()
```

or with

```
client.get_slice(toByteBuffer(rowKey), parent, predicate, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
```

I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)
```

Comment: What's the output if you do a `list aaa` in the CLI?